# Cant find App permissions in FB application for desktop web

Tags: facebook-graph-api, fbconnect

I cant find the Permissions tab in a FB application. I need to put a permission for displaying Notifications. Could someone tell me where it is hidden in this update? Or an alternative programmically?

Basic Settings contains - App ID, App secret, Display name, Namespace, App domains, Contact email, Privacy policy email, Terms of service, app icon, and category. - Before it was on this tab but now its not. It is not on advanced settings either.

Comment: displaying notifications? what permission would that be? afaik you can´t access user notifications anymore. either way, it´s in the "App Review" tab, that is where you can send permissions to review.

Comment: I cant find any tab or settings related to any permission asking at all.

Comment: i am not sure what you are talking about. there never was a tab for asking permissions, there is only the review tab where you can send permissions to review.

Comment: Before this update there was under Settings > Basic